# saving an ansible fact as a local variable

Tags: variables, ansible, ansible-facts

I'm trying to create a local variable (local as inside a task) using a variable gathered from a fact. Basically the opposite of sect_fact....

something like:

```
- name: create a variable from a fact
  create_var: 
    name: myprivatevar
    value: {{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}
```

in order to be able to use that var later, in relation to another host.

I know I can use magic variables an hostvars in order to access other hosts' facts but I dont know the names of the hosts I want to refer to when I play the book...

Comment: you can use `ansible_play_hosts` to gather the list of hosts. Telling this in context of `hostvars` approach.

Comment: Describe *"relation to another host"* and make it [mre].